# ImageMagick : Extractng images from PSD

Tags: imagemagick, libpng, psd

I'm trying to extract images from my PSD using this command :

```
 convert my_file.psd extracted/image-%d.png
```

The problem is some pictures are perfectly extracted, but about 60% are not. Here is a sample of what I get : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/78906691/image-93.png

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing the first layers. It seems like it was linked with transparency, so launched the command twice: once with the original, and once with another file in which I had removed the pictures I already got.